# Creating an instance of a Javascript class from TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to call a javascript class from Typescript but the compiler (VS) is throwing a wobbly.

The class itself is [InfoBox](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/infobox) but unfortunately I cannot find a typescript definition for it.

When I try to use it from my TS class it complains that it cannot find name "InfoBox"

```
public showInfoWindow(latLng: google.maps.LatLng, map: google.maps.Map): InfoBox {
    var infobox = new InfoBox({
    // ...
    }

    return infobox;
}
```

In the InfoBox.js file it is defined using the `prototype` method like so

```
function InfoBox(opt_opts) { ... }
InfoBox.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the class yourself, for example in a file `InfoBox.d.ts`:

```
// InfoBox.d.ts
declare class InfoBox {
    constructor(obj: any);
    // Here the members of InfoBox you use
}
```

The documentation on declaration files [is here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/writing-declaration-files.html).

Comment: I tried this, I must have got the syntax wrong, thanks!